# My table doesn't fit; what are my options?

Tags: tables, page-breaking, width, height

I have a table that I want to insert on a page, but at least one (perhaps both) of the following conditions are met:

1. The table is too *wide* to fit within the text block or page. That is, I'm exceeding some *horizontal* restriction.
2. The table is too *tall* to fit within the text block or page. That is, I'm exceeding some *vertical* restriction.

What are my options to make this table fit? If it doesn't fit, regardless of my attempts, what other options exist?

Comment: We receive a large number of questions regarding tables that "don't fit". This is meant to be a resource to address those in a generic fashion.

Comment: If a table is too large, please consider first 1) should it be a table at all, and 2) does it really need all content you're stuffing into it? Changing the table's *content* is usually much more difficult than simply adjusting some typography, but it is frequently the better solution when you want to visualize information! You should be certain that your gigantic table is the best (or least bad) solution to convey information before you go on reading the answers here. (I'm posting this as a comment and not an answer, because it's not really TeX related).

Comment: Sometimes the width of a table can be reduced by placing text into a tablenote/footnote/endnote instead of a table-cell.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Let's first identify what we're referring to when we use the term "table". The typical `table` environment is a *float*, and can contain anything: a paragraph of text, an image, or even a `tabular`. Working with the latter - a `tabular`  - and how to adjust it is what is discussed here. The discussion also applies to `array` structures since they provide a math analogue to `tabular`.

Consider reading [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764) if you're interested in *float*-specific placements.

Secondly, understand that a `tabular` is a static, two-dimensional construction. As such, it's probably best-suited for representing two dimensions (like *age* x *gender*, or *region* x *type*). Representing anything more than two dimension may therefore inherently be problematic if not presented "carefully," since the number of elements to tabulate expands *geometrically*. If you're presenting (say) three dimensions of information by (say) *age*, *gender* and *ethnicity* and the table doesn't fit, perhaps consider breaking this single table into a `tabular` by *age* and *gender* for each *ethnicity*. Remember that tables should extend or ease the digestion of the information, so if its representation seems complex, dense or confusing, separation into more elementary components might be your best option.

---

#### 1. My table/`tabular` is too wide. What can I do to make it fit?

The following are possible options to consider (in no particular order):

- If you're presenting data that has large (wide) column headings, consider *stacking* or *abbreviating* these to collapse too-wide columns:

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}
      \centering

      \begin{tabular}{ *{12}{c} }
        This&is&a&\texttt{tabular}&with&twelve&columns&that&is&just&too&wide. \\
        \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12
      \end{tabular}

      \medskip

      % Condense column headers using abbreviations or acronyms
      \begin{tabular}{ *{12}{c} }
        This&is&a&\texttt{tbl}&with&twelve&cols&that&is&just&too&wide. \\
        \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
        \multicolumn{12}{l}{%
          \footnotesize \texttt{tbl}: \texttt{tabular} title; cols: column title}
      \end{tabular}

      \bigskip

      \begin{tabular}{ *{3}{c} }
        This is a \texttt{tabular} with&three columns that is just&too wide to fit in \texttt{\string\textwidth}. \\
        \hline
        1  2  3  4 & 5  6  7  8 & 9  10  11  12
      \end{tabular}

      \medskip

      % Condense column headers via stacking
      \begin{tabular}{ *{3}{c} }
              This is           &                    &           too wide             \\ 
        a \texttt{tabular} with & three columns that &            to fit              \\
                                &      is just       & in \texttt{\string\textwidth}. \\
        \hline
        1  2  3  4 & 5  6  7  8 & 9  10  11  12
      \end{tabular}

      \medskip

      % Condense column headers via stacking
      \begin{tabular}{ *{3}{c} }
        \makecell[b]{This is \\ a \texttt{tabular} with} & 
        \makecell[t]{three columns that \\ is just} & 
        \makecell{too wide \\ to fit \\ in \texttt{\string\textwidth}.} \\
        \hline
        1  2  3  4 & 5  6  7  8 & 9  10  11  12
      \end{tabular}

      \medskip

      % Condense column headers via stacking in a paragraph-style column
      \begin{tabular}{ *{3}{c} }
        \multicolumn{1}{p{60pt}}{\centering This is a \texttt{tabular} with} & 
        \multicolumn{1}{p{7em}}{\raggedleft three columns that is just} & 
        \multicolumn{1}{p{3cm}}{\raggedright too wide to fit in \texttt{\string\textwidth}.} \\
        \hline
        1  2  3  4 & 5  6  7  8 & 9  10  11  12
      \end{tabular}

      \caption{This is a table caption.}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

Manual stacking may be tedious. Setting a column heading a fixed-width `p{<len>}`-column is a way of providing an automated way of line-breaking (also shown above).

- Allowing columns entries to wrap naturally is possible when using a `p`aragraph-style column specification. This `p{<len>}`-style column wraps at `<len>`. If you don't know what `<len>` should be, [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) can help with its flexible `X`-column:

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}
      \centering

      \begin{tabular}{ *{3}{c} }
        This is a \texttt{tabular} with&three columns that is just&too wide to fit in \texttt{\string\textwidth}. \\
        \hline
        1  2  3  4 & 5  6  7  8 & 9  10  11  12
      \end{tabular}

      \medskip

      % tabularx provides a fixed-width table with flexible columns
      \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ c X >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X }
        This is a \texttt{tabular} with&three columns that is just&too wide to fit in \texttt{\string\textwidth}. \\
        \hline
        1  2  3  4 & 5  6  7  8 & 9  10  11  12
      \end{tabularx}

      \caption{This is a table caption.}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

Justified wrapping within the `X`-columns may cause overfull `\hbox` warnings, which may be avoided by using a `\raggedright` setting. Since `tabularx` loads [`array`](//ctan.org/pkg/array), column prefixes `>{<prefix>}` can be added.

[`tabulary`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabulary) provides a similar interface and may also be helpful in this regard.

- Header *rotation* may also provide some horizontal reduction:

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \newcommand{\hd}{\rotatebox{60}}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}
      \centering

      \begin{tabular}{ *{12}{c} }
        This&is&a&\texttt{tabular}&with&twelve&columns&that&is&just&too&wide. \\
        \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12
      \end{tabular}

      \bigskip

      % Condense column headers using rotation
      \begin{tabular}{ *{12}{c} }
        \hd{This}&\hd{is}&\hd{a}&\hd{\texttt{tabular}}&\hd{with}&\hd{twelve}&
          \hd{columns}&\hd{that}&\hd{is}&\hd{just}&\hd{too}&\hd{wide.} \\
        \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12
      \end{tabular}

      \caption{This is a table caption.}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

Rotational formatting is fairly extreme visually and should be used sparingly.

- Probably the best way of attempting a horizontal fit would be to break the `tabular` is smaller, width-fitting `tabular`s. It's the least invasive visually (in general) and perhaps airs out the information for better reader digestion:

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}
      \centering
    
      \begin{tabular}{ *{12}{c} }
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
        \hline
        This&is&a&\texttt{tabular}&with&twelve&columns&that&is&just&too&wide.
      \end{tabular}
    
      \bigskip
    
      \begin{tabular}{ *{6}{c} }
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
        \hline
        This & is & a & \texttt{tabular} & with & twelve \\
        \\
        7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
        \hline
        columns & that & is & just & too & wide.
      \end{tabular}
    
      \bigskip
    
      \begin{tabular}{ *{6}{c} }
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
        \hline
        This & is & a & \texttt{tabular} & with & twelve
      \end{tabular}
      
      \medskip
      
      \begin{tabular}{ *{6}{c} }
        7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
        \hline
        columns & that & is & just & too & wide.
      \end{tabular}
    
      \caption{This is a table caption.}
    \end{table}
    
    \end{document}
```

- Consider removing horizontal content to make it fit within the width that you need. You can either remove content manually, although this might be tedious for large `tabular`s. However, if you don't want to remove the content yet still remove a column(s), read [Easiest way to delete a column?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16604/5764).

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}

    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16607/5764
    \usepackage{array}
    \newcolumntype{H}{>{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup}c<{\egroup}@{}}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}
      \centering

      \begin{tabular}{ *{12}{c} }
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
        \hline
        This&is&a&\texttt{tabular}&with&twelve&columns&that&is&just&too&wide.
      \end{tabular}

      \bigskip

      % Drop/Hide column 10
      \begin{tabular}{ *{9}{c} H *{2}{c} }
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
        \hline
        This&is&a&\texttt{tabular}&with&twelve&columns&that&is&just&too&wide.
      \end{tabular}

      \caption{This is a table caption.}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

- Consider reducing the horizontal separation between columns. The default document classes define `\tabcolsep` to be `6pt`. For `array`s the length used is `\arraycolsep` with a default of `5pt`. This may be more than you need. For a multi-column `tabular`, reducing the `\tabcolsep` could save you valuable points.

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}
      \centering

      \begin{tabular}{ *{12}{c} }
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
        \hline
        This&is&a&\texttt{tabular}&with&twelve&columns&that&is&just&too&wide.
      \end{tabular}

      \bigskip

      \begingroup
      \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.75\tabcolsep}% Reduce \tabcolsep by 25%
      \begin{tabular}{ *{12}{c} }
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
        \hline
        This&is&a&\texttt{tabular}&with&twelve&columns&that&is&just&too&wide.
      \end{tabular}
      \endgroup

      \caption{This is a table caption.}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

It may be required to limit the scope of the change to `\tabcolsep`, hence the use of grouping the `\setlength` adjustment (via `\begingroup`...`\endgroup` or `{`...`}`).

- Consider reducing the size of fonts used for the `tabular`. If using the default `\normalsize` for your document, perhaps `\small` or `\footnotesize` might make it fit:

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}
      \centering

      % This tabular is too wide
      \begin{tabular}{ *{12}{c} }
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
        \hline
        This&is&a&\texttt{tabular}&with&twelve&columns&that&is&just&too&wide.
      \end{tabular}

      \bigskip

      \begingroup
      \footnotesize% Change to smaller font from \normalsize
      \begin{tabular}{ *{12}{c} }
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
        \hline
        This&is&a&\texttt{tabular}&with&twelve&columns&that&is&just&too&wide.
      \end{tabular}
      \endgroup

      \caption{This is a table caption.}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

See [What is the default font size of a LaTeX document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155896/5764) and [What point (pt) font size are \Large etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24599/5764) for a discussion on fonts and font sizes.

It may be required to limit the scope of the change to the font, hence the use of grouping (via `\begingroup`...`\endgroup` or `{`...`}`).

- For just-too-wide `tabular`s, you can resize the entire table to fit within your bounds *horizontally* using `\resizebox{<width>}{<height>}{<tabular>}` where `<width>` is at most `\linewidth` or `\textwidth` (see [Difference between \textwidth, \linewidth and \hsize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16942/5764)). The notation `!` for `<height>` will ensure that the aspect ratio of the resizing is kept.

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}
      \centering

      \begin{tabular}{ *{12}{c} }
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
        \hline
        This&is&a&\texttt{tabular}&with&twelve&columns&that&is&just&too&wide.
      \end{tabular}

      \bigskip

      % \resizebox{<width>}{<height>}{<tabular>}
      \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{ *{12}{c} }
          1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
          \hline
          This&is&a&\texttt{tabular}&with&twelve&columns&that&is&just&too&wide.
        \end{tabular}}

      \caption{This is a table caption.}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

Scaling the `tabular` shrinks *all* the content... text included. If the factor of shrinking is small enough, there may not be a noticeable different between the fonts used in the document and the scaled `tabular`.

- Maybe you've conceded that the `tabular` *can* butt into the margin(s) because any of the above changes are just not sufficient for your needs. However, the default `\centering` doesn't set the `tabular` in a centred way, so you can set the `tabular` inside a `\makebox[<width>]` of small enough `<width>` (less than `\linewidth`) which will automatically centre it within the margin span (see [How can I center a too wide table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39435/5764)):

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}
      \centering

      \begin{tabular}{ *{12}{c} }
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
        \hline
        This&is&a&\texttt{tabular}&with&twelve&columns&that&is&just&too&wide.
      \end{tabular}

      \bigskip

      % This tabular is still too wide, but we'll keep it as-is...
      \makebox[\textwidth]{%
        \begin{tabular}{ *{12}{c} }
          1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
          \hline
          This&is&a&\texttt{tabular}&with&twelve&columns&that&is&just&too&wide.
        \end{tabular}}

      \caption{This is a table caption.}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

- You can rotate the table by 90 degrees (clockwise or counter-clockwise), placing it on its side. Typically pages are taller than they are wider, which may make the `tabular` fit. This, however, would be an extreme adjustment as you're requesting your audience to adjust their point of view and some people may not enjoy this switch between horizontal (left-to-right) and vertical (bottom-to-top) setting:

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}        
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}
      \centering
    
      \begin{tabular}{ *{12}{c} }
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
        \hline
        This&is&a&\texttt{tabular}&with&twelve&columns&that&is&just&too&wide.
      \end{tabular}
    
      \bigskip
      
      \rotatebox{90}{%
        \begin{tabular}{ *{12}{c} }
          1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
          \hline
          This&is&a&\texttt{tabular}&with&twelve&columns&that&is&just&too&wide.
        \end{tabular}}
    
      \caption{This is a table caption.}
    \end{table}
    
    \end{document}
```

[`graphicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)'s `\rotatebox{<angle>}{<tabular>}` is used to rotate the `<tabular>` by `<angle>` degrees.

The above example rotates the `tabular` *only*, leaving the caption in its original place. If you want to rotate the entire *float* - caption included, you can use a `sidewaystable` (provided by the [`rotating` package](//ctan.org/pkg/rotating)):

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}        
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}
      \centering
    
      \begin{tabular}{ *{12}{c} }
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
        \hline
        This&is&a&\texttt{tabular}&with&twelve&columns&that&is&just&too&wide.
      \end{tabular}
            
      \caption{This is a table caption.}
    \end{table}

    \begin{sidewaystable}
      \centering
    
      \begin{tabular}{ *{12}{c} }
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
        \hline
        This&is&a&\texttt{tabular}&with&twelve&columns&that&is&just&too&wide.
      \end{tabular}
            
      \caption{This is a table caption.}
    \end{sidewaystable}
    
    \end{document}
```

Note that a `sidewaystable` assumes your table is fairly *wide* and therefore will occupy most of the text block *height* during rotation. As such, the default behaviour is to place it on a page of its own.

---

#### 2. My table/`tabular` is too tall. What can I do to make it fit?

Many of the same procedures listed above can be applied *vertically* in order to adjust your `tabular` layout, like font changes, rotation or manually breaking content into multiple `tabular`s; some suggestions are listed below.

- `\arraystretch` is used to stretch (or shrink) each row within a `tabular`. Perhaps your `\documentclass` increased this. You can adjust it using `\renewcommand`:

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}

      \begin{minipage}{0.3333\linewidth}
        \centering
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}    

        \begin{tabular}{ c c }
          1&This \\ 
          \hline
          2&is \\ 3&a \\ 4&\texttt{tabular} \\ 5&with \\ 6&twelve \\
          7&rows \\ 8&that \\ 9&is \\ 10&just \\ 11&too \\ 12&tall.
        \end{tabular}

      \end{minipage}%
      \begin{minipage}{0.3333\linewidth}
        \centering
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
      
        \begin{tabular}{ c c }
          1&This \\ 
          \hline
          2&is \\ 3&a \\ 4&\texttt{tabular} \\ 5&with \\ 6&twelve \\
          7&rows \\ 8&that \\ 9&is \\ 10&just \\ 11&too \\ 12&tall.
        \end{tabular}

      \end{minipage}%
      \begin{minipage}{0.3333\linewidth}
        \centering
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}
      
        \begin{tabular}{ c c }
          1&This \\ 
          \hline
          2&is \\ 3&a \\ 4&\texttt{tabular} \\ 5&with \\ 6&twelve \\
          7&rows \\ 8&that \\ 9&is \\ 10&just \\ 11&too \\ 12&tall.
        \end{tabular}

      \end{minipage}

      \caption{This is a table caption.}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

- Consider cutting out chunks of rows and stacking them horizontally rather than keeping the content in a vertical fashion.

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}
      \centering

      \begin{tabular}{ c c }
        1&This \\ 
        \hline
        2&is \\ 3&a \\ 4&\texttt{tabular} \\ 5&with \\ 6&twelve \\
        7&rows \\ 8&that \\ 9&is \\ 10&just \\ 11&too \\ 12&tall.
      \end{tabular}

      \bigskip

      \begin{tabular}{ c c @{\hspace{2em}} c c }
        1&This & 1&This \\ 
        \hline
        2&is & 8&that \\
        3&a  & 9&is \\
        4&\texttt{tabular} & 10&just \\
        5&with & 11&too \\
        6&twelve & 12&tall. \\
        7&rows
      \end{tabular}

      \bigskip

      \begin{tabular}[t]{ c c }
        1&This \\ 
        \hline
        2&is \\ 3&a \\ 4&\texttt{tabular} \\ 5&with \\ 6&twelve \\ 7&rows
      \end{tabular}\hspace{2em}%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{ c c }
        1&This \\ 
        \hline
        8&that \\ 9&is \\ 10&just \\ 11&too \\ 12&tall.
      \end{tabular}

      \caption{This is a table caption.}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

- Reducing the font size also reduces the line height and consequently the vertical span of a `tabular`:

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}
      \centering

      \begin{tabular}{ c c }
        1&This \\ 
        \hline
        2&is \\ 3&a \\ 4&\texttt{tabular} \\ 5&with \\ 6&twelve \\
        7&rows \\ 8&that \\ 9&is \\ 10&just \\ 11&too \\ 12&tall.
      \end{tabular}%
      \hspace{2em}%
      \begingroup
      \small% Change to smaller font size from \normalsize
      \begin{tabular}{ c c }
        1&This \\ 
        \hline
        2&is \\ 3&a \\ 4&\texttt{tabular} \\ 5&with \\ 6&twelve \\
        7&rows \\ 8&that \\ 9&is \\ 10&just \\ 11&too \\ 12&tall.
      \end{tabular}%
      \endgroup

      \caption{This is a table caption.}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

Again, here, scoping might be required to limit font changes.

- `graphicx`'s `\scalebox{<factor>}` or `\resizebox{<width>}{<height>}` is an option. You can specify an appropriate height-fitting `<height>` length or portion. A `<width>` of `!` ensures to maintain the aspect ratio during resizing:

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}
      \centering

      \begin{tabular}{ c c }
        1&This \\ 
        \hline
        2&is \\ 3&a \\ 4&\texttt{tabular} \\ 5&with \\ 6&twelve \\
        7&rows \\ 8&that \\ 9&is \\ 10&just \\ 11&too \\ 12&tall.
      \end{tabular}%
      \hspace{2em}%
      \resizebox{!}{.8\height}{%
        \begin{tabular}{ c c }
          1&This \\ 
          \hline
          2&is \\ 3&a \\ 4&\texttt{tabular} \\ 5&with \\ 6&twelve \\
          7&rows \\ 8&that \\ 9&is \\ 10&just \\ 11&too \\ 12&tall.
        \end{tabular}}

      \caption{This is a table caption.}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

- If your `tabular` is just too tall, you can consider breaking it across the page boundary *manually* (that is, setting separate `tabular`s to fit on each page). This may require the use of separate floats (and perhaps [continued captions](//ctan.org/pkg/ccaption) as well). However, there are packages that can assist with such *automated* breaking: [`longtable`](//ctan.org/pkg/longtable), [`supertabular`](//ctan.org/pkg/supertabular), [`ltxtable`](//ctan.org/pkg/ltxtable), [`xltabular`](//ctan.org/pkg/xltabular) and [`xtab`](//ctan.org/pkg/xtab) are a couple such packages. [More packages are listed on CTAN](//ctan.org/topic/table-long). Also see [How can I make a table that takes up more than a single page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133/5764) or [Make a table span multiple pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26462/5764).

The following example is taken directly from the `longtable` documentation and illustrates the construction of the `longtable` environment components in order to break a table across multiple pages (with a "continued caption"):

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{longtable}

    \def\v{\char`}

    \begin{document}

    % Note: Various parts of the following table will
    % *not* line up correctly until this document has been run
    % through LaTeX several times. This is a characteristic feature of
    % this package, as described below.

    \begin{longtable}{@{*}r||p{1in}@{*}}
        KILLED & LINE!!!! \kill
        \caption
          [An optional table caption (used in the list of tables)]
          {A long table\label{long}} \\
        \hline\hline
        \multicolumn{2}{@{*}c@{*}}%
          {This part appears at the top of the table} \\
        \textsc{First} & \textsc{Second} \\
        \hline\hline
      \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{(continued)} \\
        \hline\hline
        \multicolumn{2}{@{*}c@{*}}%
             {This part appears at the top of every other page} \\
        \textbf{First} & \textbf{Second} \\
        \hline\hline
      \endhead
        \hline
        This goes at the & bottom. \\
        \hline
      \endfoot
        \hline
        These lines will & appear \\
        in place of the  & usual foot \\
        at the end       & of the table \\
        \hline
      \endlastfoot
        \texttt{longtable} columns are specified & in the \\
        same way as  in the \texttt{tabular} & environment. \\
        ``\verb~@{*}r||p{1in}@{*}~'' & in this case. \\
        Each row ends with a & ``\verb|\\|'' command. \\
        The ``\verb|\\|'' command  has an & optional \\
        argument, just as in & the \\
        \texttt{tabular} & environment. \\[10pt]
        See the effect of ``\verb|\\[10pt]|'' & ? \\
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Also ``\verb|\hline|'' may be used, & as in \texttt{tabular}. \\
        \hline
        That was a ``\verb|\hline|'' & . \\
        \hline\hline
        That was ``\verb|\hline\hline|'' & . \\
        \multicolumn{2}{||c||}%
          {This is a \ttfamily\v\\multicolumn\v{2\v}\v{||c||\v}} \\
        If a page break occurs at a ``\verb|\hline|'' then & a line is drawn \\
        at the bottom of one page and at the & top of the next. \\
        \hline
        The ``\verb|[t] [b] [c]|'' argument of \texttt{tabular} & can not be used. \\
        The optional argument may be one of & ``\verb|[l] [r] [c]|'' \\
        to specify whether the table should be & adjusted \\
        to the left, right & or centrally. \\
        \hline\hline
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Some lines may take up a lot of space, like this: &
           \raggedleft This last column is a ``\texttt{p}'' column so this
           ``row'' of the table can take up several lines. Note however that
           \TeX\ will  never break a page within such a row. Page breaks only
           occur between rows of the table or at ``\verb|\hline|'' commands.
           \tabularnewline
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        \hline
        Lots\footnote{This is a footnote.} of lines & like this. \\
        Lots of lines & like this\footnote{\texttt{longtable} takes special
           precautions, so that footnotes may also be used in `\texttt{p}' columns.} \\
        \hline
        Lots of lines & like this. \\
        Lots of lines & like this.
    \end{longtable}

    \end{document}
```

---

#### 3. My `tabular` is too wide *and* too tall for where I placed it. What can I do?

Typically one can combine the above methods for width/height improvements. There may be some incompatible choices (like resizing a `longtable`, for example).

Comment: I'm guessing you're not done here, but a common reason for having too wide tables is that the user has  a lot of text in `c`/`l`/`r` columns, and the usual fix is `p`/`X` columns, so an example of that would be useful.

Comment: some publishers consider that table captions should go at the top (and figure captions at the bottom).  other tactics not (yet) mentioned are that (1) if text in either a column heading or a cell is too wide,  can be broken into multiple lines, using a "paragraph" approach to keep appropriate baselines, and (2) if material in a particular column has repetitive elements (such as a currency unit or"%"), that can be moved to the column header.  great job!

Comment: another tactic i've seen used when only width is a problem: diagonal column headings.  this should be used only as a last resort.

Comment: Another option: When it's only the column names that are long but not the values, you can create shorthands for the names: There are two basic options, for **Geometric mean** one could use the first letters (**`GM`** or **`g.~m.`** or alike) or an arbitrary symbol such as **`(\dagger)`** **(†)**, **`(*)`** etc. Don't forget to add a legend in that case (in the caption or as a table footnote just below the last line of the table).

Comment: This is a really nice thorough answer.  It handles databook tables (for which LaTeX is surely ideal) better than any answer I've seen so far.  As @yo' says table(foot)notes can help .  They can also be used in the data cells as well as the headings, e.g. the year a widget was first sold could be writeen as "2017 (planned)" or "2107*"..."* manufacturer's planned release date".

Comment: Have you considered writing something for _TUGboat_ based on this?

Comment: @JosephWright: Not until now. :)

Comment: i second @JosephWright's suggestion.  please do consider.

Comment: Why not to use `adjustbox` instead of `resizebox` approach? - - I know both are bad, but I think equivalent alternative. Etc in fitting table into Beamer slide, example here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394693/13173

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영: How would you use [`adjustbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox)? As far as I can see, it would provide a different interface for the same thing. At best, perhaps `\adjustbox{max width = X, max height = Y}{<table>}`.

Answer (score 5):

If a document consists of pages in portrait format and the table would fit on the paper in width if you had landscape format, you can consider making a longtable rotated by 90 degrees spanning several pages.

(One might probably do that only if the table is only used for dull lookups, like a price list or similar, where it is not important to see correlations between groups of data by looking at several records at once.)

Nowadays you could use zref and the hook system recently introduced in the LaTeX2e kernel:

- For the longtable, temporarily change the layout so that page width and page height are swapped.
- In the longtable, set a label in the first and last cell using the tools of the zref package to hold the information about the absolute page numbers at the beginning and end of the longtable.
- Use the new hook system for adding to the hook that is executed before each shipout the instruction to rotate the page/the `\ShipoutBox` by 90 degrees if the absolute page number is in the range of the pages denoted by the zref-labels placed at the beginning and at the end of the longtable environment.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[abspage]{zref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter

% A scratch loop for repeating #3 while counting from #1 to #2.
% As counter is used \scratchmacro
% #3 is expanded until finding an unexpandable token.
% If the unexpandable token is a space token it is discarded.
\newcommand\scratchmacro{}
\newtoks\scratchtoks
\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}
\newcommand\scratchtoksloop[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\scratchmacro{#1}%
  \scratchtoks{\endgroup}%
  \loop 
    \scratchtoks\expandafter{\the\expandafter\scratchtoks\romannumeral`\^^@#3}%
  \ifnum\scratchmacro < #2 %
    \edef\scratchmacro{\the\numexpr\scratchmacro+1\relax}%
  \repeat
  \the\scratchtoks
}%

% This checks if the current value of the abspage-counter is within the
% range given by zref-label #1 and zref-label #2.
\newcommand\saveabspage[1]{\zref@labelbyprops{#1}{abspage}}%
\newcommand\CheckWhetherAbsPageInLabelrange[2]{%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{\@secondoftwo}{%
    \zref@ifrefundefined{#2}{\@secondoftwo}{%
      \zref@ifrefcontainsprop{#1}{abspage}{%
        \zref@ifrefcontainsprop{#2}{abspage}{%
          \ifnum\zref@extractdefault{#1}{abspage}{-1}>\value{abspage}%
          \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
          {\@secondoftwo}{%
            \ifnum\zref@extractdefault{#2}{abspage}{-1}<\value{abspage}%
            \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
            {\@secondoftwo}{\@firstoftwo}%
          }%
        }{\@secondoftwo}%
      }{\@secondoftwo}%
    }%
  }%
}%

\makeatother

% The zref-label at the start of the longtable is "tablesfirstpage".
% The zref-label at the end of the longtable is "tableslastpage".
% Add to the hook carried out at every shipout the directive to check if
% absolute page is in range denoted by these labels, and if so,
% to rotate the page/to rotate \ShipoutBox:
\AddToHook{shipout/before}{%
  \CheckWhetherAbsPageInLabelrange{tablesfirstpage}{tableslastpage}{%
    \setbox\ShipoutBox=\vbox{\hbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{%
      \vbox{\hbox{\box\ShipoutBox\kern\ifodd\value{page}\evensidemargin\else\oddsidemargin\fi}}%
    }}}%
  }{%
  }%
}%

% Just make sure...
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pagewidth}{}{\pagewidth=\paperwidth}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pdfpagewidth}{}{\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pageheight}{}{\pageheight=\paperheight}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pdfpageheight}{}{\pdfpageheight=\paperheight}%

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\newpage
\begingroup
\ifodd\value{abspage}\newpage\else\newpage\null\newpage\fi
% ---- Layout ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%      For typesetting the longtable temporarily change the layout so that
%      width and height of page are exchanged and textwidth is increased etc:
\pagestyle{plain}%
\csname zref@ifrefundefined\endcsname{tablesfirstpage}{%
  \paperwidth=\the\expandafter\paperheight
  \expandafter\paperheight\expandafter=\the\paperwidth
  \csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pagewidth}{}{\pagewidth=\paperwidth}%
  \csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pdfpagewidth}{}{\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth}%
  \csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pageheight}{}{\pageheight=\paperheight}%
  \csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pdfpageheight}{}{\pdfpageheight=\paperheight}%
  \textwidth=\paperwidth
}{%
  \textwidth=\paperheight
}%
\advance\textwidth-3cm\relax
\evensidemargin=\dimexpr-1in+1.5cm\relax
\oddsidemargin=\dimexpr-1in+1.5cm\relax
\marginparsep=2mm\relax
\marginparwidth=\dimexpr2cm-2\marginparsep\relax
\csname zref@ifrefundefined\endcsname{tablesfirstpage}{%
  \textheight=\paperheight
}{%
  \textheight=\paperwidth
}%
\advance\textheight-3cm\relax
\topmargin=\dimexpr-1in+1.5cm\relax
\headheight=0pt\relax
\headsep=0pt\relax
{\normalfont
 \setbox\csname @tempboxa\endcsname\hbox{0123456789}%
 \footskip=\dimexpr 1cm -.5\dp\csname @tempboxa\endcsname
                        +.5\ht\csname @tempboxa\endcsname\relax
\expandafter}\expandafter\footskip\expandafter=\the\footskip
\csname @colht\endcsname=\textheight
\csname @colroom\endcsname=\textheight
\vsize=\textheight
\columnwidth=\textwidth
\hsize=\columnwidth
\linewidth=\hsize
\parindent=0pt\relax
% ---- Layout-changes done. --------------------------------------------------------
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|}
\caption{Caption of Longtable}\label{LongtableLabel}\\
\hline
\saveabspage{tablesfirstpage}number&left&middle&right\\
\hline\endfirsthead
\hline
number&left&middle&right\\
\hline\endhead
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{This is a clever remark.}\\
\hline\endfoot
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{This is a clever remark.\saveabspage{tableslastpage}}\\
\hline\endlastfoot
\scratchtoksloop{1}%
                {100}%
                {%
                  \expandafter\hbox\expandafter{%
                    \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond
                    \expandafter{\scratchmacro}{\hphantom{100}\llap}%
                  }%
                  &left&middle&\scratchtoksloop{1}{11}{ this is wide }\\%
                }%
\end{longtable}%
\newpage
\endgroup
% ---- After typesettig the longtable reset the page layout ------------------------
\csname @colht\endcsname=\textheight
\csname @colroom\endcsname=\textheight
\vsize=\textheight
\columnwidth=\textwidth
\hsize=\columnwidth
\linewidth=\hsize

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]